# ¿Cómo obtener la decena superior?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio dónde obtengo la decena del número , pero ahora me interesaría obtener la decena superior a la que obtengo.

Es decir si paso un 76 , la decena superior sería 80.

Alguna idea para hacerlo ?

```
 public static int calcularDecena(int decena){
        int calcular;
        calcular = decena/10;
        return calcular;
    }
```

Saludos y muchas gracias !

Answer (score 5):

Te dejo el código, básicamente es restar lo que te sobra de la decena y sumarle 10.

```
public static int calcularDecena(int decena){
    int calcular;
    calcular = decena - (decena%10) + 10;
    return calcular;
}
```

Se puede hacer aun mas corta:

```
public static int calcularDecena(int decena){
    return decena - (decena%10) + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que utilizar la operación módulo:

```
decsuperior = numero + (10-(numero%10));
```

Módulo te devuelve el resto de la división entera, en este caso 76 % 10 = 6. (76/10 es igual a 7 y resto 6).

10 - el resto, te dice cuánto te falta para la siguiente decena.

Answer (score -1):

Hola puedes intentar haciendo esto:

```
 public static int calcularDecena(int decena){
    int calcular;
    calcular = decena/10;
    calcular = (calcular + 1) * 10
    return calcular;
}
```

Multiplicamos por 10 para sacar esa decena mayor. 
Ej:
43/10 = 4;
4 + 1 = 5;
5 * 10 = 50;

Espero te sirva.